# How to write multiple queries in a single tables.sql file and upload it using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

All I want is to create 2 or more tables using `tables.sql` file via PHP.

## PHP `create_db.php`

```
<?php
require 'config.php';


$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
/* check connection */
if($mysqli->connect_errno){
  echo "MySQL connection failed.<br>";
  exit();
}else{
  echo "MySQL successfully connected.<br>";
}

// DB create
if($mysqli->query('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS '.DB_NAME.';') === TRUE){
  echo "Database successfully created.<br>";
}else{
  echo "Error: ".$mysqli->errno.", ".$mysqli->error."<br>";
}

// DB select
if($mysqli->select_db(DB_NAME) === TRUE){
  echo "Database successfully selected.<br>";
}else{
  echo "Error: ".$mysqli->errno.", ".$mysqli->error;
}

// Create tables
if($mysqli->query(file_get_contents('../sql/tables.sql')) === TRUE){
  echo "Tables successfully created.<br>";
}else{
  echo "Error: ".$mysqli->errno.", ".$mysqli->error."<br>";
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

*DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME are defined in config.php file*

> PHP v7.4.7

### SQL `tables.sql`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `status` (
  `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `IDtime` varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
```

*If I upload this tables.sql file directly to MySQL server using command line it is working.*

> MySQL v8.0.20 MySQL Comunity Server - GPL

#### Error message

> Error: 1064, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `status` ( `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL, `IDt' at line 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqli::query only accepts single query https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php.

If you want to execute multiple queries at once you have to use mysqli::multi_query https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php.

Example:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM reservations;SELECT * FROM reservations");
var_dump($result, $mysqli->error);

bool(false)
string(172) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM reservations' at line 1"


$result = $mysqli->multi_query("SELECT * FROM reservations;SELECT * FROM reservations");
var_dump($result, $mysqli->error);

bool(true)
string(0) ""
```